# Live Plotting with PyQtGraph in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqtgraph

I am quite new in Python and TRYING to make a PyQt4 app, where I am embedding PyQtGraph in it. I've got this PyQtGraph live plotter that works fantastically:

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg
import random

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
p = pg.plot()
curve = p.plot()
data = [0]

def updater():

    data.append(random.random())
    curve.setData(data) #xdata is not necessary


timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(updater)
timer.start(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

For embedding in a bigger PyQt4 app, I need a layout for including a pyqtgraph.PlotWidget(). For that matter I set a centralWidget in my MainWindow. I create a button, that should start plotting just as the previous code does, but just nothing happens when I call the updater function through the plotter function:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg
import random

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.central_widget = QtGui.QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        login_widget = LoginWidget(self)#to say where the button is
        login_widget.button.clicked.connect(self.plotter)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(login_widget)

    def plotter(self):
        self.data =[0]
        timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        timer.timeout.connect(self.updater)
        timer.start(0)

    def updater(self):

        self.data.append(random.random())
        plot.setData(self.data)

class LoginWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        global plot
        super(LoginWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Start Plotting')
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        plot = pg.PlotWidget()
        layout.addWidget(plot)
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Is nothing happening because I have to thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several things to consider in the code.
First, going in the same direction as @luddek's answer, you need to keep track of your variables. If you define a variable inside a class method and this class method finished executing, the variable is lost. Also it is not visible from the outside.
It is therefore a good idea to use instance variables,
`self.plot` instead of `plot`
`self.timer` instead of `timer`
`self.login_widget` instead of `login_widget`
(also, I would not recomment using `global` in a PyQt programm, although it is valid code)

Next, `PlotWidget` does not have a `setData` method. Plotting the data to the PlotItem's plot is a little more involved:
`pg.PlotWidget()` has a `PlotItem` which you can get via `.getPlotItem()`. Then you need to invoke `plot()` on it, which returns the actual curve you want to add data to. In the example below I introduced the new variable `self.curve` to which you can add the data via `self.curve.setData(self.data)`

Here is the complete working code.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg
import random

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.central_widget = QtGui.QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.login_widget = LoginWidget(self)
        self.login_widget.button.clicked.connect(self.plotter)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(self.login_widget)

    def plotter(self):
        self.data =[0]
        self.curve = self.login_widget.plot.getPlotItem().plot()

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updater)
        self.timer.start(0)

    def updater(self):

        self.data.append(self.data[-1]+0.2*(0.5-random.random()) )
        self.curve.setData(self.data)

class LoginWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LoginWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Start Plotting')
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.plot = pg.PlotWidget()
        layout.addWidget(self.plot)
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I am really trying to get my variable scope understanding up and running, but it takes me some time. Lucky me you guys are passionate programmers :-) Also I didn't find the correct use of pg.PlotWidget() in the documentation.....Thanks again!

Comment: If this solved your issue, consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). If not feel free to refine your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

`updater()` is not called because the timer is removed by the garbage collector.

You need to keep a reference somewhere to the timer. You could for example create the reference in `__init__`

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    ...
    self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
```

Comment: While this is correct, preventing the timer from being garbage collected is only part of the whole problem.